# How to close a DB2 cursor from OLEDB client?

Tags: db2, oledb

I have client utility that uses OLEDB to call a DB2 stored procedure. Inside the stored a procedure a cursor is opened so my utility can read record sets. Everything works fine but after a while of calling the same procedure over and over again, DB2 eventually throws an error that is related to the cursor being left open. Is there a sql command in DB2 to close the last used cursor or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to do it from the client, but in the sp the code should be calling
 `Close CursorName;`. Can you not update the procedure?

[See here for an example.](http://www.fluffycat.com/SQL/Cursor-DB2/)